# Change window properties (Size, position) by title

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to find a way to change that properties of existing window that was not initially created by python but did not find any document for doing that.

The action that I’m trying to perform is the change the size and position of existing internet explorer window but I want to change a window that has a specific title and not all internet explorer windows.
Does someone knows that answer for this question?
Thanks.

Comment: I know a way using not python but `nircmd` tool.

Comment: Thank you but I'm looking for the Python way.
From the reseach that I did it seems like it is not possible unless someone know a way.

Comment: with win32com api I'm sure it can be done using python.

Comment: I have this extention already but the problem is that I didnt find any related funtion for controling existing windows.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution for this issue (win32gui):
Example for the usage:

```
    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow('Notepad', 'Untitled - Notepad')
    win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd, 600, 300, 500, 500, True)
```